# Right align text in HTML input field

Tags: html, css, filter, tags, text-alignment

I have an HTML  tag with a short maxlength but a long value attribute.  I'd like the displayed text to show the *end* (right side) of the text, rather than the start (left side).

```
<input maxlength=10 value="A really really really long entry goes in here"/>
```

currently shows:

"A really r"

instead I'd like it to show:

"es in here"

Cheers,

Ian

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you want the visible area to start from the right? you can use css and the following rule `input {direction:rtl;}`

`rtl` means from right to left

example: http://jsbin.com/ilejo4

PS: the value of `maxlength` in your html must be wrapped with quotes, also you have to set the `type` of the `input`

Comment: Strangely, if the value starts with a slash `/` (like a filename) - that slash is pushed to the "end" which is now the right side of the string.  Use this with care.

Comment: -1 "rtl" does not keep the order when there is punctuation and numbers! Be careful. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53947553/22470

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="text-align:right"` to the input tag.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Shouldn't the time for inline-style be over since years?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display information, what you can do is place a span inside a div, in the div write overflow:hidden, display flex, justify-content: flex-end;

```css
.contenedor{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor"><span>12345555555566final</span></div>
```